# GET REST API using Slim Framework 3 Skeleton

Tags: php, rest, slim

I am learning how to build an API using PHP and Slim Framework, I made a test called "data" to get an array:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');

error_reporting(1);

require '../../slim/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App;

function response($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\App::getInstance();
    $app->status($status_code);

    $app->contentType('application/json');
    return json_encode($response);
}

$app->get('/data', function () {

    $response = array();

    $data=array(
        array('Foo'=>'Foo', 'Bar'=>'Bar'),
        array('Lorem'=>'Ipsum', 'Dolor'=>'Sit Amet')
    );

    $response["error"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "datas: " . count($data);
    $response["data"] = $data;

    return response(200, $response);
});
```

When I call the api using /data I got a status 200 empty response.

This is the url: http://sandboxweb.bailac.net/gts_benja/api/v1/data

What is wrong and what I need to do to get the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally got it, Slim 3 needs return a slim object (like body, write and withJson), the following code works for me:

```
$app->get('/data', function ($request, $response){

    $data=array(
        array('Foo'=>'Foo', 'Bar'=>'Bar'),
        array('Lorem'=>'Ipsum', 'Dolor'=>'Sit Amet')
    );

    return $response->withJson($data);
});
```

the followings ways to return worked for me too:

```
return $response->body(json_encode($data));
return $response->write(json_encode($data));
```

I prefer `withJson` method to avoid using `json_encode`.

Thank you Alex Howansky for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't `echo` the response, `return` it:

```
function response($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\App::getInstance();
    $app->status($status_code);
    $app->contentType('application/json');
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

And then in your handler function:

```
return response(200, $response);
```

Comment: I edited it as you said, but still giving me an empty response, I going to edit my post with these changes and add the url.